# clang-format stream output

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format formats my code as follow:

```
std::cout << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1
          << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1;
```

but my style-guide requires:

```
std::cout << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 <<
    1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1 << 1;
```

I tried setting BreakBeforeBinaryOperators:None and AlignOperands:false, but it didn't help me. Is there any other options?

Comment: maybe set AlignOperands to false ?

Comment: Is your required style guide based on one of the [styles clang-format provides presets](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options) for? This might be a good starting point.

Comment: AlignOperands:false didn't help

Comment: I tried all builtin styles (LLVM, Google, Chromium, Mozilla, WebKit) but they all align << one below the other.

Comment: And following the mainstream is not an option?  :-)

Comment: your style guide sucks - sorry, but i can not understand why the guide requires to make the code less readable since the whole purpuse of style guides is to help writing readable code

Comment: I dislike it because it requires mixing indentation in a project that uses tabs without a significant readability benefit.