# Clang format stop operators aligning on wrap

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-format

clang-format is formatting like this:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Camera& c ) {
    return os << c.latitude << ", " << c.longitude << ' ' << c.state << ' ' << c.county << ' '
              << c.description;
}
```

this is despite me turning off all alignments, and looking through all the wrapping settings I can find, my desired effect is just one tab indentation instead of the streams being aligned, like so:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Camera& c ) {
    return os << c.latitude << ", " << c.longitude << ' ' << c.state << ' ' << c.county << ' '
         << c.description;
}
```

I'm using `AlignOperands: DontAlign` and clang-format-17

Comment: Linked to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699555/clang-format-stream-output